# SQL Server 2000: Invalid column name 'bar'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I think I just found a weird bug in SQL Server 2000.

The following query returns an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'bar'

If I execute the same exact query in SQL Server 2005, it will work. It also works if I `select  #weirdness.*`. Is there some workaround that can be used in a procedure? I know `go` helps, but it cannot be used in a procedure. BTW, we are going to get rid of SQL Server 2000, but it takes time.

```
select 1 as  foo
into #weirdness;

alter table #weirdness add bar int identity;

--select  #weirdness.*    --works
select #weirdness.bar  --fails
from #weirdness;
```

System:

> Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2066 (Intel X86)   May 11 2012 18:41:14
>   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the workarounds I could think of for now.

**If possible use SQL Server 2005 or newer.**

**If possible split the script into multiple batches (not possible in a procedure):**

```
select  1   as  foo
into    #weirdness;

alter table #weirdness add bar int identity;

go  --split into multiple batches

--select  #weirdness.*    --works
select  #weirdness.bar  --fails
from    #weirdness;
```

**Create the table first:**

```
create table #weirdness (
    foo bit
,   bar int identity
);

insert into #weirdness(foo)
select  1   as  foo;

select  #weirdness.bar
from    #weirdness;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, it's documented behavior. Try this on for size:

```
select 1 as foo into #weirdness;
go
alter table #weirdness add bar int;
select #weirdness.bar
from #weirdness;
```

You'll see that this fails in SQL Server 2005 as well, complaining that "bar" does not exist.

Why does it fail? Because, per [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms175502), you're not allowed to do that:

> A table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the
>   same batch.

So why does creating and altering a table and then referencing it nevertheless work if we do it in one batch in SQL Server 2005, but not in SQL Server 2000? That has to do with statement recompilation, which is also documented in the above, and new in 2005.

In SQL Server 2005, because `#weirdness` doesn't exist at the start of the batch, SQL Server doesn't compile the statements referencing it. The `select .. into` is executed, and all statements referencing it are marked for recompilation. These statements are then compiled and executed one by one. By the time we reference `#weirdness.bar`, it has been created and compilation succeeds.

In SQL Server 2000, because `#weirdness` doesn't exist at the start of the batch, SQL Server doesn't compile the statements referencing it. The `select .. into` is executed, and the whole batch is marked for recompilation. But compiling `select #weirdness.bar` fails since the `alter table` has not been executed, and the batch stops.

So, the documentation should actually read "a table cannot be changed and then the new columns referenced in the same batch, unless the table happened to not exist at all when the batch started, then you can get away with this stuff from SQL Server 2005 onwards, but it's probably not such a hot idea to rely on that". You can see why they kept it simpler.